# Карта растягивается по вертикали

Tags: ios, yandexmapkit

1. Быстро прокручиваем карту.
2. Пока инерция не успела завершиться, изменяем границы Map View. Например, в случае открытия или закрытия наэкранной клавиатуры.
3. Вся карта растягивается по вертикали, включая логотип Яндекса на ней, и остаётся в таком состоянии навсегда.

Как это можно исправить? iOS 11.

[image]

Comment: ios 11 уже едва ли актуальна для какой-либо разработки. На свежей версии OS и MapKit ситуация актуальна?